# What does ▽ mean in 곤란 (困難▽)?

Tags: vocabulary

The [entry for 곤란](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/m/eng/searchResultView?wordMatchFlag=N&currentPage=1&mainSearchWord=%EA%B3%A4%EB%9E%80&sort=&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=27668&font_size=12&nationCode=6&nation=eng&viewType=A) in the *National Institute of Korean Language's Korean-English Learners' Dictionary* has 困難▽ listed for the Hanja. Is this a bug/error in the dictionary or does it actually mean something in Korean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error. From the [preface of the dictionary](http://stdweb2.korean.go.kr/guide/origin.jsp):

> (1)
>
> 한자의 원래 음과 한글 표기로 제시되는 음이 다른 경우에는 해당 한자 오른쪽에 '▽' 기호로 표시하였다. 그러나 사이시옷이 첨가된 형태나 어문 규정의 차이로 달리 표기한 북한어에는 표시하지 않았다.
>
> <예> 
> 시월01 (十▽月) , 찻-잔 (茶盞), 페경지(廢耕地)

Roughly translated, it says:

*When the original sound of the hanja and the sound that is expressed using Hangul does not match, the '▽' symbol is used to mark such cases. However, forms with 사이시옷 and North Korean words which follow different set of orthography rules are not marked.*

These irregularities are due to historical sound changes.

Some other important dictionary symbols:

- `▼` is used to mark that the word in the original language is nonexistent.
- `-` (a hyphen) is used at the border of morphemes in compound words. You should never put a space instead of the hyphen when using that word.
- `^` is used when spacing is optional.

Comment: In other words, read the manual :) Thanks! Is this a common character used in dictionaries or just this one?

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding... when a sound is not possible in Hangul, the ▽ is used to express that in writing, but how is it said? Or, is it simply not said since it is no possible to use it?

Comment: I’m just curious… from what angle do Koreans consider the pronunciation “deviant”? Many characters have multiple pronunciations, sometimes because the Chinese had multiple pronunciations, and sometimes because of semi-regular sound changes within Korean.

Both **리** and **이** are considered canonical readings of **李** even though the latter is a phonological change. Based on Chinese rime dictionaries, only **리** would be correct.

Comment: In the majority of the words marked with **▽**, I noticed that the change seems to be from **ㄴ** to **ㄹ** where the original Chinese also had a dental nasal initial (**ㄴ**). The more common **ㄹ** to **ㄴ** change is ignored.

Comment: @KevinLi Word-initial ㄹ changing into ㄴ, and 리 changing into 이 is a super regular sound change with no exceptions(it's not considered historical), so I guess that's why they're not marked. ㄴ to ㄹ change is much more rare, so they're marked to avoid confusion.